# WP7 - Adding MessageHeader to WCF Soap Service Calls

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, soap

I've spent the last two days trying to configure my WP7 app to send message headers to my WCF Soap Service. I'm simply trying to send a string of information on every call.

There is an abundance of guides online but I can't seem to piece them together to get what I want done and could really do with some help.

So - could somebody please help me with the SIMPLEST way to add a message inspector to my service and attach headers from within my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WP7 - there's no "simple" way to do that. Most extensibility points in WCF aren't present in the WP7 platform, so you have a couple of alternatives.

The easiest way is to use the `OperationContext` to add outgoing message headers. It's fairly simple (see below), but you need to do that for every operation you call:

```
var client = new ServiceReference1.MyServiceClient();
client.OperationCompleted += ...;
using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
        MessageHeader.CreateHeader(
            "headerName", "http://header.namespace", "the value"));
    client.OperationAsync(param1, param2);
}
```

If doing that in all operations is too much, an alternative is to create a class which wraps the client, and does that for all the operations. Still a lot of code, but at least it will be concentrated in one point, instead of being spread throughout your application.

The last alternative (which I can remember now) is to use message inspectors. They're not part of the platform, but depending on your scenario, I've implemented one support for inspectors / formatters as shown in the blog post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/21/wcf-extensibility-extensibility-in-windows-phone-and-silverlight-3.aspx. For simple scenarios it should work fine.